# Dictionary of types in typescript?

Tags: generics, dictionary, typescript

i have class hierarchy that looks like this:

```
interface TypeI {
    getName(): string;
}

class ClassA implements TypeI{
    static name: string = "A"
    getname(){
        return ClassA.name;
    }
}

class ClassB implements TypeI{
    static name: string = "B"
    getname(){
        return ClassB.name;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make Dictionary of types that implement TypeI in typescript? Something like this:

```
var typedDictionary: { [<T extends TypeI>] : T };
typedDictionary[ClassA] = new ClassA();
var a: ClassA = typedDictionary[ClassA];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dictionary of types that implement TypeI in typescript?

Keys for objects in javascript *can only be a string*. If you pass in something that is not a string then `toString` will be called on it. So no, you cannot have a type `T` as a key ... only a `string`.

You could however abstract over it in a class and that is something like this generic Dictionary does: https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections#a-sample-on-dictionary

Comment: Maybe add toString method to TypeI?

Comment: @АндрейАндреев you are right. That was my intent so I clarified it.